# What Should We Do About Tags With Different Meanings Depending on the Context

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

What should we do about tags that can mean different things depending on their context? For example, [mirror](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mirror)*(although I'm sure there are many others)*. Mirror can mean: mirror modifier, mirror material or a mirror model. Should we make tags specifically for each one?

The primary reason I'm bringing this up is because it makes tag definition much harder.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

More than likely, for tags like these there already exists another with which it can correlate to bring across its meaning or the scope of the question.

For example, [mirror](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mirror) as you used it could have [modifiers](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modifiers), [materials](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/materials) or [modeling](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modeling) to go along with it. In a worst case scenario we could have a question that entails all 3 *(or more)* like;

**Q: Why does the *material* distort when I use the *mirror modifier* and *extrude*?**

In such a case, it will be easy enough for the same reason we decided not to use version specific tags, once the question is being read, it will be made clear as to what is being asked. Also note that tags in general play very little in deciding what a question is *entirely* about.

Comment: The reason I'm bringing this up is because it makes tag definition harder.

Comment: @CharlesL did you read the last line? *note that tags in general play very little in deciding what a question is entirely about.* Tags can only tell so much about a question, at most they set the scope, attract more views and popup in searches. If in doubt, use the one that the majority of the question is about.

Comment: OK, makes sense. Thanks :D